# iOS app goes to background on launch

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cllocationmanager

I wrote an app in Swift 3, which on launch goes to background instead of prompting for Allow app to access user location, after upgrading to iOS 11.1.

Answer (score 0):

Found that app would throw an assertion:

```
Assertion failure in -[CLLocationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:]
```

In my code, I found this line which I removed to solve the problem:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```